# A Flutter widget and its state: a chicken-and-egg problem

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

As you can see in the code below, `createState()` runs after the constructor of `MyWidget` has completed, and hence the `keyword` is available.

But despite that the constructor of `MyWidgetState` runs *after* the constructor of `MyWidget`, uncommenting the `print()` in the former fails. The `widget` seems not to be ready.

If the chicken-and-egg problem is clearly settled: the widget is created first, why can the state not access the widget variable in its own constructor? `widget` is accessed inside `build()` just fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(keyword: 'keyword'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String keyword;

  MyWidget({Key key, this.keyword}) : super(key: key) {
    print('In _MyWidget(): ${keyword}');
  }

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  _MyWidgetState() {
    // print('In _MyWidgetState(): ${widget.keyword}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return Text(widget.keyword);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not answer your questin but you need to use `initState` instead of trying to do anything with the constructor of `_MyWidgetState`. That is the first thing that happens in the stateful part of the widget, and its before the build method.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String keyword;

  MyWidget({Key key, this.keyword}) : super(key: key) {
    print('In _MyWidget(): ${keyword}');
  }

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('In _MyWidgetState(): ${widget.keyword}'); // this will print
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.keyword);
  }
}
```